# My number textbox in jquery mobile increases a lot after one click

Tags: jquery-mobile, razor, textbox

I've made a jquery mobile number box that lets people press up or down to increase the number in the textbox:

```
<input type="number" name="IdeaValue" id="IdeaValue" value="@item.Value" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" style = "width: 100px; float: left;"/>
```

However, when I click the up or down button, the numbers increase really fast instead of one number increase for each click. Anybody know what could cause this?

Comment: Show your buttons js code, please.

Comment: I'm a little new to this. I thought I was just using the javascript code that's included in the jquery-mobile library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
$('#btUp').click(function(){
    $('#IdeaValue').value($('#IdeaValue').value() + 1);
});
$('#btDown').click(function(){
    $('#IdeaValue').value($('#IdeaValue').value() - 1);
});
```

**NOTE**: I used the up button click event to increment the "input" value and down button click event to decrement it.